# How to convert apk into tpk file

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, tizen, tizen-web-app

How to convert apk into tpk file. please suggest me if any authenticate site is available to download apk to tpk converter.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you even google it?

Comment: theres a lot of online converters.. Try those..

Comment: Please try to gogle it first , there are many converters online

Comment: Please tell me the link.

Comment: Please search for it.

Comment: No Links available to download apk to tpk converter. Please provide some links to do conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Well apparently this is not such a straight forward operation.

Tizen devices do not ship with Android capabilities. But there is a project aiming to enable Android apps to run on a plathora of environments called [OpenMobile](http://www.openmobileww.com/). The task is then accomplished by installing [OpenMobile's ACL (Application Compatibility Layer)](http://www.openmobileww.com/products-and-services/how-acl-works/) first, and then installing the Android apps on top of it.

Here is a video demonstrating running an Android app on a Samsung Z1:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ARdA4Ikzfc

---

Also - from the [Tizen tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tizen/info):

> With HTML5's robust capabilities and cross platform flexibility, it is
>   rapidly becoming the preferred development environment for mobile apps
>   and services.

Tizen is barely 1.1% of Samsung's own device sales, so this raises the question: who writes those lies? :)

Comment: No Links available to download apk to tpk converter. Please provide some links to do conversion.

Comment: @AnbarasanG I don't think you've read my answer. There is no "magical" way to convert apks to tpks.